# Почему может различаться поведение transpose из numpy и torch7?

Tags: numpy

**upd. ошибка скрывалась в другом месте, проблема решена.**

На входе в обоих случаях - четырёхмерный массив (хранит пачку изображений в виде [imageCount, width, height, colorChannel]). Однако возвращаемые `tensor:transpose(2, 4)` и `numpy.transpose(tensor, (0, 3, 2, 1,))` результаты различны.

Если подробнее:
Был код на Lua

```
local tmp_target = torch.Tensor(buffer_size, 224, 224, 3):float()
fastReadFloat(path, tmp_target) -- just fill tensor with data
return return tmp_target
```

Результат сохраняю с помощью `npy4th`.
И нa python

```
depth_flat = numpy.fromstring(depth_bytes, numpy.float32)
depth = depth_flat.reshape([image_count, 224, 224, 3])
return depth
```

Сверяю следующим кодом :

```
print("Python data shape", numpy_data.shape)
print("Torch data shape", torch_data.shape)
assert numpy_data.shape == torch_data.shape
error = mean_squared_error(numpy.array(numpy_data.flat), numpy.array(torch_data.flat))
print("Error value is ", error)
assert error <= max_error
```

Его выхлоп :

```
Python data shape (1000, 224, 224, 3)
Torch data shape (1000, 224, 224, 3)
Error value is  0.0
```

Теперь пытаюсь изменить "форму" массива (нужно - 10000, 3, 224, 224, т.е.  [imageCount, colorChannel, height, width]).

```
local tmp_target = torch.Tensor(buffer_size, 224, 224, 3):float()
fastReadFloat(path, tmp_target)
return tmp_target:transpose(2, 4)

depth_flat = numpy.fromstring(depth_bytes, numpy.float32)
depth = depth_flat.reshape([image_count, 224, 224, 3])
transposed_depth = numpy.transpose(depth, (0, 3, 2, 1,))
return transposed_depth
```

В результате же

```
Python data shape (1000, 3, 224, 224)
Torch data shape (1000, 3, 224, 224)
Error value is  16540.1
```

Comment: Поделитесь в чем была причина ошибки?

Comment: Таки я некорректно подгружал данные. Завел под это отдельный тест и обнаружил проблему :-)